# Permutations: Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, permutations

> How many permutations are there of the set $(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)$

My Answer:

Since there are 7 elements in the set, $7! = 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 5040$

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: If you do not allow repetition, then yes, that is correct.

Comment: Almost right. Refine your answer to "$7$ **distinct** elements".

Answer (score 2):

Almost right - refine your answer to "$7$ **distinct** elements".

More generally, given a collection (aka *multi-set*) of:

- $m_1$ identical elements
- $m_2$ identical elements
- $\ldots$
- $m_n$ identical elements

The number of permutations of the elements in it is:

$$\frac{n!}{{m_1!}\cdot{m_2!}\cdot\ldots\cdot{m_n!}}$$